# How can I warn users about their quotas only once?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-space-utilization, quota

I have a number of accounts on a Linux server that have filesystem quotas.  I would like to email people only once for each of the following circumstances:

- The person goes over quota.
- The person's quota grace period ends.
- The person goes back under quota.  (This one might be optional.)

In particular, I do *not* want a person who is over quota to get a new email every day until they go back under quota.  They should get a maximum of three emails (one for each of the events above).

The standard `warnquota` program, as far as I can tell, simply emails everyone that's over quota every time it's run.  That has the potential to generate a lot of mail and does not fit my requirements.

Is there another program that will meet my needs, or will I have to write something myself?

My file server is running RHEL 5.  If I really need, I could mount its filesystem via NFS on a RHEL6 or RHEL7 system and run the quota-warning program from the client.

Comment: IMHO you will spend more time trying to find such a program than writing it by yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I wrote a program:

https://github.com/asciiphil/quotanotify

Maybe it will be useful to someone else, too.